# Setting mapping DHTMLX

Tags: dhtmlx

Is there a way to have attribute mapping in DHTMLX tree grid as we have in gantt charts? For example if we have set for a column id ="Age", it should look for that attribute in the incoming JSON data and automatically map it to appropriate column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setColumnIds command

```
mygrid.setColumnIds("sales,book");
```

And use column ids for data mapping

```
mygrid.parse([
    { id:1, sales:"1220", book:"The BestSeller"}
], "js")
```

and for loading from the external source

```
mygrid.load("data.php", "js")
```

The key point here is the usage of "js" as data loading type.